# Understanding HTTP error in Azure Web App log file output

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, http, identity, http-status-code-302

I have a net core web app which presents a login page when run locally & in Azure web App Service. Without any explanation so far it has just started erroring in Azure Web App Service. To the best of my knowledge I have not altered any code that would have changed this. Github builds are from YAML. No changes registered in Github.

I have used Chrome dev tools and enabled diagnostics logging for apps in Azure App Service. I thought the logging may give me more info.

To summarize. The comparison URL output for my local v Azure app launching is as follows:

```
https://localhost:44357/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

https://example-app-service-rollbase.azurewebsites.net/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FError%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FHome%252FError ... etc ...
```

In dev tools
local = HTTP 101
Azure = HTTP 302 Found (Too many redirects. The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Try clearing your cookies)

Using the following in Azure CLI:

```
az webapp log tail --name example-app-service-rollbase --resource-group example-resources --provider http
```

I launch the app and record the log output. To me it's more confusing than the problem (for brevity I have trimmed out time/date/browser type and reference links & am printing consecutive lines of output):

```
EXAMPLE-APP-SERVICE-ROLLBASE GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=fffed190-2641-4ebd-b4b8-1e3034635ffe 443 - 121.74.116.232
```

The above output being: Web App name, HTTP method, Azure Resource Reference-LOG-ID? & my public IP address (I am behind a firewall on a private network)

```
EXAMPLE-APP-SERVICE-ROLLBASE GET /Identity/Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2F&X-ARR-LOG-ID=dc48d20d-4859-4956-95e0-020c6f592afd 443 - 121.74.116.232
```

Here is where the problem shows up. The returnURL. My understanding is that %2F returnUrl typically just exists as a mechanism to point back to the previous page.

```
EXAMPLE-APP-SERVICE-ROLLBASE GET /Identity/Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FError%3FReturnUrl%3D%252F&X-ARR-LOG-ID=ec2e323b-b593-4272-8b61-b9b72245255d 443 - 121.74.116.232
```

Here an encoded '?' is added (%3F) And from here the returnURLs pile up.

At about this point I don't understand what I am seeing. Other than the same information I got from dev tools.

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As a security measure, Azure employs this pairing and matching of redirect URI with `reply URLs` to stop third parties from abusing your application by trying to authenticate using your Azure application coordinates and sending the access token to their application instead of yours.

I made another authorization URL using a redirect URI parameter that my Azure application hasn't set up as a legitimate `reply URL`.

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/1c3d2eea-12db-2ec3-437e-2eec7289e1a1/oauth2/authorize
> ?client_id=ef92a29b-b332-9d43-1341-23326315fa42
> &response_type=id_token+token
> **&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fpdogs-babel.azurewebsites.net%2Fcallback.html**
> &state=12345
> &nonce=678910
> &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F

Here I’ve set the  *redirect_uri* parameter to ***[https://pdogs-babel.azurewebsites.net](https://pdogs-babel.azurewebsites.net/)***, and send this to the authorization endpoint, the following error message…

> AADSTS50011: The reply address  **https://pdogs-babel.azurewebsites.net/callback.html** does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: ef92a29b-b332-9d43-1341-23326315fa42.

Someone could be able to obtain an access token using your application coordinates if you are using the implicit grant route. The browser sends the initial authorization URL via HTTP, and the authorization endpoint replies with a _HTTP 302 [Found] response with a *Location* header value containing the URL found in the *redirect uri* parameter together with the hash fragment holding the *access token*.

[image]

Please find more information on [Platinum dogs article](https://platinumdogs.me/2016/04/25/understanding-the-oauth2-redirect_uri-and-azure-ad-reply-url-parameters/).